# Can Omniture be implemented within Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

Has anyone successfully included Omniture tracking code within a custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager? If so, is it just a matter of dropping the standard Omniture code in, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2):

From a purely coding perspective, technically it is possible. However, currently GTM enforces a max container size (I don't remember offhand how many bytes) that is smaller than the current Adobe Analytics (Omniture) core library size.

So, it is technically possible if you are willing to break that core code up into multiple chunks. But Adobe does not officially support doing this, and will not offer any kind of assistance for problems you may have, if you do so.

I have several clients who use GTM and we put custom coding (config stuff, s_doPlugins, etc.) in GTM but the core AA library remains a standalone file hosted on the client's site.